# How do I create a repeating number sequence in a column in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to create a query that returns a column with a repeating number sequence in it.

For example:

```
row_num | repeat
----------------
   1    |   1
   2    |   2
   3    |   3
   4    |   1
   5    |   2
   6    |   3
```

I'm struggling to understand how I could achieve this with BigQuery Standard SQL.
So far i've generated the row number `(ROW_NUMBER() OVER()) as row_num` in my select, and then I was thinking I could use a modulus function to determine the repeat number, but this would split it into several separate columns, so I'd need additional steps to merge them into the one column. I wondered if there was a more elegant way of achieving this.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Obviously the `MOD(ROW_NUMBER() OVER() - 1, 3) + 1 AS repeat` is the way to go - but can you share your real use case - what it is that you are trying to address by doing this? so we can more effectively help you

Comment: As is usually the case when I read the answers to my SO questions, I'm currently slapping my forehead. Thanks, @MikhailBerlyant! In answer to your question, I'm trying to partition my data so that it can be evenly divided up and processed by several parallel processes external to BigQuery, without the need for a queue or anything similar. The modulus computation could have been handled in the external processes, but I wondered if I could achieve this in BigQuery instead.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the modulus should work here.  Assuming your table already has a `row_num` column, and you want to generate the `repeat` column, you may try:

```
SELECT
    row_num,
    MOD(row_num - 1, 3) + 1 AS repeat
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    row_num;
```